# how to prove that this problem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Is there partial laplace derivative equations? I am so confused.

Show that the function provides the equation.

\begin{equation}
    \label{simple_equation0}
 u = {\varphi }(xy)+\sqrt{xy}{\psi}(\frac{y}{x})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \label{simple_equation1}
 x^{2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^{2}}-y^{2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^{2}}= 0
\end{equation}

Comment: @Eric Towers phi function whats mean ? I do not content of function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &= -\frac{y^2 \psi '\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{x^2 \sqrt{x y}}+\sqrt{x y} \left(\frac{y^2 \psi ''\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{x^4}+\frac{2 y \psi '\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{x^3}\right)-\frac{y^2 \psi \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}{4 (x y)^{3/2}}+y^2 \varphi ''(x y)  \\
   &= \frac{\sqrt{x y} \left(4 y \left(x^3 \sqrt{x y} \varphi ''(x y)+y \psi ''\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+x \psi '\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)-x^2 \psi \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)}{4 x^4}  \text{.}
\end{align*}